# Gnuplot how to represent calligraphied letters

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I am using LaTeX and Gnuplot-5.2. In several graphs, I need to represent a calligraphied letter (e.g., L) which in LaTeX math equations appears as \mathcal L.

How to represent a calligraphied letter in Gnuplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use one of the latex terminals. In gnuplot console type `set terminal` to see which terminals you have available.

Another option would be if you search for `cmsy10.ttf` and install the font and use it in gnuplot. This is as it would work in Windows, I'm not 100% sure for Linux.

**Addition:**
Check `help enhanced` to see options about enhanced text mode. Not all terminals might support this.

**Code:**

```
### set different fonts
reset session

set title "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" font "cmsy10,20"

myLabel = '{/"cmsy10":Normal=20 L{/"Times New Roman":Normal=20 (w)}}'
set label at graph 0.5, graph 0.8 myLabel

plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:** (wxt terminal)

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Your solution is perfect. Just one more point since I have to represent \mathcal L(w) where (w) are in the form of regular characters (i.e., not calligraphied ones). Any ideas?

Comment: It is perfect, theozh! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @aquarelle332 glad to hear. Thanks on StackOverflow = upvote and/or accept.

Comment: I agree however SO says: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @aquarelle332 well, below 15 reputation you can accept answers.Check the checkmark.